# reshape a pandas DataFrame by transposing two columns and repeating another

Tags: python, pandas

The title might be a bit confusing, this is what I want to do:

I would like to convert this dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C'],'date1':[1999,2000,2001],'date2':[2011,2012,2013]})

   date1  date2 name
0   1999   2011    A
1   2000   2012    B
2   2001   2013    C
```

Into the following:

```
   dates name
0   1999    A
1   2011    A
2   2000    B
3   2012    B
4   2001    C
5   2013    C
```

I've been trying to do pivot tables and transposing, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), remove column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars='name', value_name='dates')
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
         .sort_values('name')[['dates','name']])
   dates name
0   1999    A
3   2011    A
1   2000    B
4   2012    B
2   2001    C
5   2013    C
```

Another solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
print (df.set_index('name')
         .unstack()
         .reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
         .sort_index()
         .reset_index(name='dates')[['dates','name']])

   dates name
0   1999    A
1   2011    A
2   2000    B
3   2012    B
4   2001    C
5   2013    C
```

Solution with `lreshape` and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
print (pd.lreshape(df, {'dates':['date1', 'date2']}).sort_values('name')[['dates','name']])
   dates name
0   1999    A
3   2011    A
1   2000    B
4   2012    B
2   2001    C
5   2013    C
```

Numpy solution with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and flattening by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "name": np.repeat(df.name, 2),
        "dates": df[['date1','date2']].values.ravel()})
print (df2)
   dates name
0   1999    A
0   2011    A
1   2000    B
1   2012    B
2   2001    C
2   2013    C
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.